# Profile time consumed in setting up function calls in C

Tags: c, function, profiler, function-call

Is there a way for me to profile the time consumed in setting up function calls and returns (Not the actual time consumed by the function code) such as stack copy and clear?
I am using gnu/linux and I am open to using any profiler however I am currently using gprof and vtune.
The problem statement is I have a lot of small functions such as multiply, addition, division etc. Most of the functions are already inlined, but there are still many functions which need to be called. And I would need to call these functions more than a million times for my given problem, however the functions only do basic computation and then return, so what I am thinking is that the actual function call might be taking longer than the computation itself.
Please advise.

Comment: That's going to be extremely difficult without manually determining which instruction should be considered as part of the calling. It's up to the compiler to decide how to do things, and the instructions associated with a call aren't necessarily adjacent to the call instruction. Actual runtime will also be affected by how instructions end up fitting in the caches.

Comment: Why is it that these functions need to be called, and can't be inlined? Some code would be good to see what you're trying to do. Also, if this is x86-64, only the return address will end up on the stack for a simple function call with relatively few relatively small arguments.

Comment: I was going to say that the most straight-forward way to measure that seems to be to have inlined and non-inlined versions of functions that take the same number and types of arguments as the ones you're interested in, and then calling them a large number of times in separate tests while measuring the overall performance of each run.

Comment: Thank you both, I am trying to inline most of the functions, and I will try doing as @500-InternalServerError suggested.